# On a javascript calendar, the month starts on Sunday, but weeks start on monday

Tags: javascript, calendar, weekday

I must modify a code in javascript that is used extensively, so I would like to not have to recreate the entire calendar code. I need the week to start on Monday, which works actually, except when the month starts on Sunday (for example March 2020). This following code (using getDay) apparently creates the number of empty cells necessary.

```
                    for(let i=1; i<date.getDay(); i++)
                {
                    let cell = document.createElement('span');
                    cell.classList.add('cell');
                    cell.classList.add('empty');
                    this.content.appendChild(cell);
                }
I'm hoping there is a way to append this when the first day of the month is Sunday. Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I corrected it. Reminder: we are creating the appropriate number of empty cells for each month.

```
                var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
                var firstDayWeek = firstDay.getDay();

                if (firstDayWeek > 0){
                    for(let i=1; i<date.getDay(); i++)
                    {
                        let cell = document.createElement('span');
                        cell.classList.add('cell');
                        cell.classList.add('empty');
                        this.content.appendChild(cell);
                    }
                } 

                else {
                    for(let i=0; i<6; i++)
                    {
                        let cell = document.createElement('span');
                        cell.classList.add('cell');
                        cell.classList.add('empty');
                        this.content.appendChild(cell);
                    }                       
                }
```